# What are files of wubi?

Tags: wubi

I was messing up with my system files when i noticed some odd-looking files.

Just wanted to know what all files are put up by wubi installed and where?
Here are few files i believe to exist:

- wubildr.mbr - In the root partition of windows (c:\ ).
- wubildr - In the root partition of windows (c:\ ).
- Adds a line to boot.ini in windows' root ( C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu" )
- Directory named "Ubuntu" - Containing all the main files for Ubuntu_OS.

What all files are added and what all windows files are modified by wubi?
Can I manually remove these files to remove Ubuntu if i don't want to uninstall via wubi ?
Does wubi make any modifications to the windows boot loader aswell ?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming That you installed everything in your windows root directory, it being C:\ 
The Following files are added up by Wubi :

- C:\ubuntu\ - The directory where Ubuntu is installed.
- C:\wubildr.mbr - The master boot record only for Ubuntu
- C:\wubildr* - Other miscellaneous files to help boot Ubuntu
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi] - Registry key to show Wubi under Add/Remove Software

The Following files are modified:

- Windows Xp - **C:\boot.ini** - Adds this line **C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"**
- Windows 98 - **C:\config.sys** - Adds this line **C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"**
- Windows 7 - Open cmd and use **bcdedit** command to search for the {GUID} specified for the Ubuntu entry.
  One may delete it with this command **bcdedit /delete {GUID}** if needed.

Yes, To manually uninstall Wubi and Ubuntu, you may safely delete all the above said files.

To the best of my knowledge (tough not sure); no changes are committed to windows boot loader.